# Return image using restler

Tags: php, restler

Is it possible to use Luracast Restler to return an image? Something like calling:

```
http://myserver.com/api/users/002/avatar
```

to download a png?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to serve images with Restler.

You need to do the following in your **API method**

- Set the content type header for the right image type (png, jpeg etc)

  ```
  header("Content-Type: image/png");
  ```
- echo the image content

  **Example**

  ```
  $im = imagecreatefrompng("test.png");

  header('Content-Type: image/png');

  imagepng($im); //this sends the image as the response
  imagedestroy($im);
  ```
- use exit or die to stop execution instead of the usual return result

Comment: That sounds a lot easier than what I was getting into: extending the Format class to serve pngs... Thanks

Comment: An imageloader http client is setting the Accept header to image/*, and now Restler complains "Content negotiation failed. Try 'application/json'". Should I add an empty ImageFormat class with MIME="image/*" ? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, you need to add a dummy ImageFormat class